# use jenkins github user credentials to access github api in my script

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins job `foo` that works perfectly well. It is authenticated with `jenkins_foo_user`. It is able to clone the repo and checkout the right branch.

In my codebase, I have another script - `query_github.py` a script used to query Github API to get information such as commits and pull request. To be able to use this API I need an access token.

I want to be able to use the jenkins user access token to authenticate and access the github credentials. 
How do I do this? 
Note: Using the Github Enterprise version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one has to use the `credentials api`.
Example

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
    credentialsId: 'jenkins-user',
    usernameVariable: 'Foo_USERNAME',
    passwordVariable: 'Foo_PASSWORD']]) {
      export foo_name=${stds.escape4sh env.Foo_USERNAME}
      export foo_pass=${stds.escape4sh env.Foo_PASSWORD}
      python foo.py
```

Inside of foo.py

```
_name = os.env.get('foo_name')
_pass = os.env.get('foo_pas')
```

easiest and cleanest way to accomplish the goal!
Note: `jenkins-user` should be configured into jenkins user credentials

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Branch Source Plugin with GitHub App authentication, you don't have a token at hand in Jenkins. But the credentials provider is smart enough to give you an access token derived from the App with just the same `withCredentials` step:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'id-of-your-github-app-credentials',
                                  usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_APP',
                                  passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN')]) {
  // Use the access token via $GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN here
}
```

Note that you have to use `usernamePassword` as type, even if your credentials referenced by ID are of type GitHub App.

See [official Jenkins blog post n GitHub App authentication](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/04/16/github-app-authentication/#how-do-i-get-an-api-token-in-my-pipeline) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a password parameter in jenkins job and the same can be used in your github script.

Ex : You can define a password variable either as a build param or a new password variable using inject global passwords ( provide u have this plugin)

The same password can be used in script which use api

Below command uses github api call and will list down repos in your organization

Make sure `<your_organization_name_HERE>` is replaced with your organization name

```
curl --silent -q  -H "Authorization: token ${github_api_pwd}" https://api.github.com/orgs/<your_organization_name_HERE>/repos
```

Similarly you can get other information using other api's